# Check if date is in This Week

Tags: formula, date, datetime

I want to check if today is with in This Week in Salesforce formula. I tried to do this via Date() function, but there is no THIS WEEK function. If there a workaround?

I don’t have a solid code, so that’s why I didn’t include it.

I am using this code to check for This Month, so I want something similar to it for THIS WEEK.

```
IF(YEAR(Date_Field__c) = YEAR(TODAY()) && MONTH(Date_Field__c) = MONTH(TODAY()), do_1, do_2)
```

Comment: have you checked [Sample Date Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this was fixed by getting the week number and comparing it with today.

```
MOD(FLOOR( (Date__c -DATEVALUE(Datefield ))/7),52)+1
```